# String split comma and parenthisis-JAVA

Tags: java, string, split

Convert the string: 
"(id,created,employee(id,firstname,employeeType(id), lastname),location)" 
to the following output 
id
created
employee
- id
- firstname
- employeeType
-- id
- lastname
location

is there any optimistic solution available with using regular expression

Comment: Yes, there is. How does your current one look like?

Comment: split is what you are looking for?

Comment: my current one is not working actually..  if you have a solution can you post please.. here is how i want it .

Comment: id
created
employee
- id
- firstname
- employeeType
-- id
- lastname
location

Comment: Show your code and explain what the problem is. We won't just do it for you.

Comment: @Pras: You will be downvoted into oblivion if you don't post the code that you have so far. This is not a "please-write-code-for-me" site.

Comment: String.split and a regex

Comment: nevermind i wrote the solution

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "(id,created,employee(id,firstname," + 
             "employeeType(id), lastname),location)";
    StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(a, "(), ");
    System.out.println("StringTokenizer example");
    while (tok.hasMoreElements()) {
        String b = (String)tok.nextElement();
        System.out.println(b);
    }
    System.out.println("Split example");
    String[] array = a.split("(),");
    for (String ii: array) {
         System.out.println(ii);
    }

 } 
}
```

Outputs

```
StringTokenizer example
id
created
employee
id
firstname
employeeType
id
lastname
location
Split example
(id
created
employee(id
firstname
employeeType(id)
lastname)
location)
```

You can add the hyphens.

Comment: Why doesn't split split on parentheses?